# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined using Axios Post request

Tags: reactjs, e-commerce

I am trying to create categories with admin permission using Reactjs and Axios. But I can not reach my goal getting a type error: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined. Things look good to me but I am a beginner. If someone can help I will be grathful...my english is awful, sorry for that

```js
const AddCategory = () => {

    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false)


//On destruture user à partir du localstorage
    const {user, token} = isAuth(); 
    //  console.log('ISAUTH:', isAuth())
    
    

    const handleChange =  (e) => {
        setError('')
        setName(e.target.value)
    }
    const clickSubmit = e => {
       e.preventDefault()
       setError('')
       setSuccess(false)
       
       //Reaquette API pour créer les catégories
     CreateCategory(user._id, token, {name})
        .then(data => {
            if(error) {
                setError(true)
            }else {
                setError('')
                setSuccess(true)
            }
       });  
    };
```

```js
import axios from "axios";



 const CreateCategory = (userId, token, category) => {
        return (
                axios({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/category/create/${userId}`,
                    headers: {
                        Authorization:`Bearer ${token}`
                    },data:{category},
                    
                })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('ADD CATEGORY RESP.', response);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('ADD CATEGORY ERROR', error) 
                })
        )}
        

export default  CreateCategory
```

. Thanks in advance. Let me show you code

```js
//My Route
router.put("/category/:categoryId/:userId", requireSignin, isAuth, isAdmin, update);
```

Comment: Hi, the problem here is that we don't know what isAuth does. User object returned from isAuth is right?

Comment: Thank you Marco for your help. The output of  console.log('ISAUTH:', isAuth()) gives me all the user informations:

Comment: But i don't see neither a  property user nor a property token

Comment: Hi Marco Moretti It's been while but  I finally solved my problem. Category was created from the front side of my app without token's or user's issue. I did this:
- const category = new Category(req.body.category)
instead of
- const category = new Category(req.body)
Thank you so much for your support and advises. Thank for your  hepl.